# Question about line integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to solve the following problem:

The shape of a jump rope is given by the function

$$ h(x) = 3(0.5 - x^{2}) \text{ where } \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq x \leq \frac{+1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

and has a total mass of 1 kg. The rope is rotating about the x-axis with one fiull rotation in one second. Determine the total length $L$ of this rope. Then it is easy to find the specific mass $\rho$ in kg/m

The solution is

$$L = \int_{C}^{}1\:ds \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$ 
$$= \int_{-a}^{a}\sqrt{(1 + (6t)^2)}\:dt \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
$$= \int_{-a}^{a}\sqrt{(1 + 36t^2)}\:dt \tag{3}\label{eq3} \approx 3.44 [m]$$

This leads to 
$$\rho = \frac{M}{L} \approx 0.29 \: [\frac{kg}{m}]$$

Here are my questions:

- how it is possible to get from (1) to (2)
- what does the function $h(x)$ exactly physically represent)

**EDIT**

(thanks to @PatrickJankowski)

the length of the rope has to be parametrize in function of time.
We can then write: 
$$c(t) = (t, h(t)) \quad \text{or} \quad x(t) = t, y(t)=h(t) $$
hence 
$$\dot{x(t)} = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \dot{y(t)} = 6x $$
hence 
$$L = \int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{\dot{x(t)}^2 + \dot{y(t)}^2} \:dt$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get from (1) to (2), parametrise h(x), so put $x = t$,
then $h(t) = 3(0.5-t^2))$

let the path of the rope be $\mathbf c (t)$
so $\mathbf c (t) = (t, 3(0.5 - t^2))$ for $t \in \Big [\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Big]$

now, $\mathrm d s = \Big \lvert \frac{\mathrm d \mathbf c}{\mathrm d t} \Big \rvert \mathrm \ dt$

$$\frac{\mathrm d \mathbf c}{\mathrm d t} = (1, 6t)$$
so $$\Big \lvert \frac{\mathrm d \mathbf c}{\mathrm d t} \Big \rvert = \sqrt{(1) + (6t)^2} $$
so then you replace $\mathrm d s$ with $\Big \lvert \frac{\mathrm d \mathbf c}{\mathrm d t} \Big \rvert \mathrm dt$ which is $\sqrt{(1) + (6t)^2} \mathrm dt$

Comment: many thanks @PatrickJankowski. What does now the function $h(x)$ represent? And about your function $\textbf{c}(t) = (t, 3(0.5-t^2))$: where does your first $t$ come from after the equal sign? Is $c(t)$? is it the position of the end of the rope in polar coordinate?

Comment: To calculate the line integral the rope is considered a path, as time $t$ increases, the position on this path will change. Putting $x=t$ just simplifies the parametrisation, so think of the $x-y$ axis as now a $t - h(t)$ axis, so on the original graph if we move to the right, we move along the curve (the rope). So now think of it like we're moving along the curve over an increasing time interval, or on a path (which is $\mathbf c$) - this means $x=t$ (the first t after the equal sign) and the second term is the location that we are at on the curve at $t$ seconds.

Comment: As for the physical interpretation of $h(x)$, it is the shape of the rope which is interpreted as a path

Comment: I hope you understand, it's hard to explain hahaha

Comment: many thanks @PatrickJankowski: I tried to reformulate what you said in the edit of the question. Can you tell me if it's correct of it's totally wrong?

Comment: it's wrong because you said $c_1 = t$ and $c_2 = h(t)$ but the way you wrote it, you made two new paths which isn't the case. Replace $c_1(t)$ and $c_2(t)$ with $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ because $t$ and $h(t)$ are the $x$ and $y$ components of the path $c(t)$ respectively

Comment: i find it helps me when i do these types of problems to always write the statement $\mathrm d s = \Big \lvert \frac{\mathrm d \mathbf c}{\mathrm d t} \Big \rvert \mathrm \ dt$ cos especially with all these line integrals, it gets crazy trying to remember them all. Good luck :)

Comment: Ok many thanks @Patrick Jankowski. Just last point: is on purpose that you wrote a "$\cos$" after the statement in you last comment?

Comment: ohhh i meant because, sorry I should be careful on this website with that ;)

Comment: No worries @PatrickJankowski. Many thanks for your help